# Allow filtering history to only show changes within a specific section

Tags: feature-request, documentation

The history link under each example filters the topic history to only those changes that touch the respective example. The other sections, however, don't have such a feature, and the history link at the end - under Remarks - shows the whole history of the topic.

It'd be nice, if we could also see filtered histories for the other sections: Syntax, Parameters and Remarks.

Comment: And show the current full-topic history under the title.